# Laravel 5.2 getNameOrUsername method not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am searching for data, as in usernames. I got it to work by using a static name like `<p>Jordan1</p>` but when I want to make it dynamic as in having my actual users' name reflect on the page it doesn't work when I used this method

```
{{ $user->getNameOrUsername() }}
```

In return I get this error:

> BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2130:
>
> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getNameOrUsername()

---

### userblock.blade.php

```
    <div class="media">
        <a class="pull-left" href="#">
            <img class="media-object" alt="{{ $user->getNameOrUsername() }}" src="">
        </a>
        <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="media-heading">
            <a href="#">{{ $user->getNameOrUsername() }}</a>
            </h4>
                @if ($user->location)
                    <p>{{ $user->location }}</p>
                @endif
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

### results.blade.php

```
@include('layouts.--header')

<div class="container">
    <h4>Your search for "{{ Request::input('query') }}"</h4>

    @if (!$users->count())
        <p> No results found, sorry.</p>
    @else
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            @foreach ($users as $user)
                @include('search.userblock')
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
    @endif
</div>

@include('layouts.--footer')
```

---

### SearchController.php

```
<?php

namespace SCM\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use DB;
use SCM\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Requests;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function getResults(Request $request)
    {   
        $query = $request->input('query');
        
        if (!$query) {
            return redirect ()->route('welcome');

        }

        $users = User::where(DB::raw("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name)"), '
            LIKE', "%{$query}%")
            ->orWhere('username', 'LIKE', "%{$query}%")
            ->get();

        return view('search.results')->with('users', $users);
    }
}
```

---

### routes.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Routes File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you will register all of the routes in an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This route group applies the "web" middleware group to every route
| it contains. The "web" middleware group is defined in your HTTP
| kernel and includes session state, CSRF protection, and more.
|
*/

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/login', function () {
    return view('auth/login');
});
    Route::get('/register', function () {
    return view('auth/login');
});

});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();
    
    Route::get('/', [
    'as' => 'welcome', 'uses' => 'WelcomeController@index'
]);

    Route::get('/profile', function () {
    return view('layouts/-profile');
});

    Route::get('profile/{username}', function () {
    return view('layouts/-profile');
});

    Route::get('settings/{username}', function () {
    return view('layouts/-settings');
});

    Route::get('/settings', function () {
    return view('layouts/-settings');
});


    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});

/**
* Search
*/
Route::get('/search', [
    'as' => 'search.results', 'uses' => 'SearchController@getResults'
]);
```

Comment: I don't see the method you've created `getNameOrUsername()`. Blade will simply let you do `{{ $user->name or $user->username }}` though. Perhaps your question isn't clear.

Comment: Forgot to add I got this error

BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2130:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getNameOrUsername()

Comment: I'm guessing your `User` model doesn't have a `getNameOrUsername()` method. Did you define it? Can you post your model?

Comment: Nevermind your solution works! Thank you!

Comment: @patricus that is what looks to be the case.

Comment: @LukeVaughan Sounds good. I posted an answer for you, with a little extra info.

Comment: `it doesn't work` - explain. Or you suggesting, that we can read your mind?

Comment: @ankhzet He posted the code that caused the error, and the error itself. What mind reading is needed? A solution and the reason why are both in these comments.

Comment: @Strum your solution worked as well, it does the same thing :)

Comment: @Sturm, browser lagged, there was no 'post edited' reminder/comments. And comment can't be deleted now =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looking for the `getNameOrUsername()` method on your `User` model. You need to define this method.

FYI, if it doesn't find the method on your `Model`, it looks for it on the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` object. If it doesn't find it there, it looks for it on the `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` object. If it doesn't find it there, it throws the exception. That's why it is a "BadMethodCallException" on  `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder`.

Answer (score 0):

That method doesn't ship with Laravel. If you want to use it you'll need to create it. I think could do something like this:

**User Model**

```
public function getNameOrUsername() {

    return $this->name ? $this->name : $this->username;

}
```

Then use it in your blade template like

`Hi {{ $user->getNameOrUsername() }}`